# Robot Framework's SeleniumLibrary throws an error "WebDriverExeception: Message : chromedriver executable needs to be in PATH"

Tags: environment-variables, robotframework

I have been trying to test RPA Framework's keyword, execute JavaScript , but still got same error like :

`chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home`

I did edit environment variables of course!

[User System environment variables Edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41kJd.png)

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: It means exactly what it says: the chromedriver executable (chromedriver.exe if you're on windows) needs to be in a folder that is on your PATH, and it's not.